# routing in .net 3.0 - route parameters and action parameters

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

.net core 3.0 web app with razorpages and api

My api controllers are in a folder "/api" and one of them has a default Get method that I want to call with both a route parameter AND 2 other values

```
[HttpGet("{customer}")]
public IActionResult Get(string customer, string size, string color)
```

Trying to route using a parameter to a path like this
    http get localhost://site-root/api/mycontroller/ABC?size=val1&color=val2
Where "ABC" would get mapped to a route parameter "customer" in my controller
but this wont route.

... in configured routing in Startup

```
 app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
        endpoints.MapControllerRoute(name: "api", pattern: "api/[controller]/[action]");
        endpoints.MapRazorPages();
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be in how you are registering the route. It should be:

```
 app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
        endpoints.MapControllerRoute(name: "api", pattern: "api/[controller]");
        endpoints.MapRazorPages();
    });
```

In your code, you are expecting an "[action]", therefore, the "ABC" text is being mapped as an action and not as an argument to the function.